# Joining query sql server

Tags: sql-server, join

I'm after some help please i'm new to SQL, can you help me join these to queries below I want all the data from the first query to be displayed and only the information that matches to be showed on the second query.

Part and subkey1 is the join

Thank you.

```
SELECT RHeads.[Document],
    RLines.Part,
    RHeads.Supp,
    RHeads.DATETIME,
    RLines.Unit,
    RLines.CQty,
    RHeads.POrder,
    RHeads.Corder,
    RHeads.Branch
FROM RLines
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN RHeads ON RLines.[Document] = RHeads.[Document]
WHERE (RHeads.DATETIME >= DATEADD(MONTH, - 3, GETDATE()))
    AND (RHeads.Corder = '02022076')
ORDER BY RHeads.DATETIME DESC;

SELECT Mvpr.Prefix,
    Mvpr.SubKey1,
    Mvpr.SubKey2,
    Mvpr.A12
FROM Mvpr
    INNER JOIN vwProduct ON Mvpr.SubKey1 = vwProduct.KeyCode
WHERE (Mvpr.Prefix = 'c');
```

Comment: Define "information that matches". The columns in both queries do not appear to have kind of relation.

Answer (score 0):

Just stick both of these SQL statements into their own subquery (using parantheses) and give each subquery an alias so we can refer to it's result set in the main query:

```
SELECT
    t1.*,
    t2.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT RHeads.[Document],
            RLines.Part,
            RHeads.Supp,
            RHeads.DATETIME,
            RLines.Unit,
            RLines.CQty,
            RHeads.POrder,
            RHeads.Corder,
            RHeads.Branch
        FROM RLines
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN RHeads ON RLines.[Document] = RHeads.[Document]
        WHERE (RHeads.DATETIME >= DATEADD(MONTH, - 3, GETDATE()))
            AND (RHeads.Corder = '02022076')
    ) t1
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   (
        SELECT Mvpr.Prefix,
            Mvpr.SubKey1,
            Mvpr.SubKey2,
            Mvpr.A12
        FROM Mvpr
            INNER JOIN vwProduct ON Mvpr.SubKey1 = vwProduct.KeyCode
        WHERE (Mvpr.Prefix = 'c') 
   ) t2 ON t1.Part = t2.SubKey1
ORDER BY t1.DATETIME DESC;
```

We're using a LEFT OUTER JOIN to get all of the records from `t1` (first query) and only those records that match from `t2` (second query).

Also I have moved the ORDER BY clause to the main query as you can't ORDER inside of a subquery (and even if you were allowed to, the ordering would be lost after the join so it would be superfluous).

Since you aren't doing any aggregating here, you could probably rewrite this without the subquery too.

I've made some assumptions about your data, but perhaps something like:

```
SELECT RHeads.[Document],
        RLines.Part,
        RHeads.Supp,
        RHeads.DATETIME,
        RLines.Unit,
        RLines.CQty,
        RHeads.POrder,
        RHeads.Corder,
        RHeads.Branch,
        Mvpr.Prefix,
        Mvpr.SubKey1,
        Mvpr.SubKey2,
        Mvpr.A12
    FROM RHeads 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN RLines 
            ON RLines.[Document] = RHeads.[Document]        
        LEFT OUTER JOIN vwProduct
            ON Mvpr.SubKey1 = vwProduct.KeyCode
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Mvpr
            ON vwProduct.KeyCode = Mvpr.Subkey1
            AND Mvpr.Prefix = 'c'
WHERE
    RHeads.DATETIME >= DATEADD(MONTH, - 3, GETDATE())
    AND RHeads.Corder = '02022076'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the granularity of the 1st query put them in CTEs and check existence:

```
;WITH Q1 AS(
    SELECT RHeads.[Document],
        RLines.Part,
        RHeads.Supp,
        RHeads.DATETIME,
        RLines.Unit,
        RLines.CQty,
        RHeads.POrder,
        RHeads.Corder,
        RHeads.Branch
    FROM RLines
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN RHeads ON RLines.[Document] = RHeads.[Document]
    WHERE (RHeads.DATETIME >= DATEADD(MONTH, - 3, GETDATE()))
        AND (RHeads.Corder = '02022076')    
), Q2 AS (
    SELECT Mvpr.Prefix,
        Mvpr.SubKey1,
        Mvpr.SubKey2,
        Mvpr.A12
    FROM Mvpr
        INNER JOIN vwProduct ON Mvpr.SubKey1 = vwProduct.KeyCode
    WHERE (Mvpr.Prefix = 'c')
)
SELECT q1.* 
FROM Q1 q1
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM Q2 q2
    WHERE q1.Part = q2.SubKey1
)
ORDER BY q1.DATETIME DESC
```